# Export a function with a c-style name?

Tags: d

Such that on windows, in C, I could do like so

```
void (*add)(int,int) = GetProcAddress(hDlangMod, "add");
add(422,244);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `extern (C)` to remove name mangling if that's what you want, be aware that it will remove some features like overloading on the D side, but if you need the function being easily accessible from C, its a great solution! You can read more about it and other techniques in https://dlang.org/spec/interfaceToC.html

TLDR: Just define it as `extern (C) void GetProcAddress(your params here)` and link it appropriately, and it will work.

Note: The same `extern` directive can be used to import symbols from C or export to C++, along with other languages and uses, its quite a useful tool!
For example: https://dlang.org/spec/cpp_interface.html